# Order of execution in useEffect: get data from API and then update parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

Due to routing, I need to use stateless components with hooks. Unfortunately I am having problem with order of execution.

I want the children component (NewComment) to call an API (send comment to database) and after doing so the parent component should reload (the NewComment component should trigger *forceReload* hook from parent component). After reloading we should see the new comment.

However, I am unable to force the order of execution in useEffect hook. My goal is to trigger the hook after successfully sending the comment to the database. Backend reports 200 OK status code after sending comment.

Sending comment works properly, forceReload also works if I call it manually after the fetch request.

useEffect:

```
    export const NewComment = ({ articleID, commentID, forceReload, reload }) => {
      const formRef = useRef(null);
      var isAutoFocus = commentID ? true : false;
    
      const submitComment = async () => {
                  obj...
        };
    
        const requestOptions = {
             ...they work
        };
    
        await fetch('/submit-comment', requestOptions);
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const listener = (event) => {
          if (
            event.keyCode === 13
          ) {
            submitComment().then(forceReload(reload + 1)) // Here I want to submitComment, wait for it successful resolve and only then forceReload should be invoked
          }
        };
        document.addEventListener('keydown', listener);
        return () => {
          document.removeEventListener('keydown', listener);
        };
      }, []);
```

Comment: Your `submitComment` method isn't returning the `fetch` promise nor are you manually resolving the promise. Simplest fix could be to simply replace `await` with `return`. I would also recommend googling how `async` functions work in JS.

Comment: Unfortunately replacing `await` with `return` doesn't help neither. Also typical chain to save in state data from response doesn't work in my case:

    `fetch('/submit-comment', requestOptions).then(() => {
      forceReload(reload + 1);
    })`

Comment: Hmm, take a look at this [working CodeSandox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-bush-vz1rq?file=/src/NewComment.js) - go to CommentPage and hit enter. Other thing to double check - are you running your API on the same port and IP as the react dev env? You may need to specify the API URL correctly.

Comment: API works correctly, also reload function works. Whenever I write comment and press separate button with reload function it shows the comment.

The current code still firstly executes forceReload and then receives information that the comment was sent successfully. I need firstly confirmation, then forceReload but it doesn't work...:
`await fetch('/submit-comment', requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(`response to submit-comment: ${data}`);
      })
      .then(forceReload(reload + 1))`

Comment: `fetch('/submit-comment', requestOptions)       .then((response) => response.json())
.then((data) => {
    // console.log(data) or whatever you want to do;
    // you don't need another .then()
    forceReload(reload+1);
});`